# What does the percent symbol (%) mean in Android.mk?

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk

In most Android.mk files I find a line that runs something like this:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
```

I understand that this line takes the expression on the right of `:=` and assigns it to the symbol `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`. I understand that `$(LOCAL_PATH)` takes the value of the `LOCAL_PATH` symbol. But I'm left with two questions:

1. What is the `%=%` part all about?
2. What's the significance of nesting the symbol `$(LOCAL_PATH)` within the broader `$(FILE_LIST:...)` expression?

Is this an ordinary makefile syntax (I'm not all that familiar with makefiles) or something else? Where would I find a guide to this syntax? (Don't tell me the [Android.mk](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/ANDROID-MK.html) guide: it doesn't deal with the % symbol.)

Example values might help us talks about this. Let's say that `$(LOCAL_PATH)` is `/Users/Jeff/dev/`. Let's say that `$(FILE_LIST)` without further complication is `/Users/Jeff/dev/aaa.c /Users/Jeff/dev/bbb.c /Users/Jeff/dev/ccc.c`. How does the above assignment lead to a useful value for `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android makefiles are intended to be run using [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/).  The documentation is available [online](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/) and also should come with your distribution.

The syntax you're asking about are [substitution references](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html); basically, the `%` is a wildcard that matches zero or more characters, and matches on the left are replaced with the right side.

So `$(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)` removes the string `$(LOCAL_PATH)/` from the start of the `FILE_LIST` variable value (if it's there; if not no change is made).

Answer (score 1):

This is [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make) syntax, to substitute the value of a string variable. In this case, take a list of strings, and for each string that begins with `/Users/Jeff/dev/`, cut this *prefix* off.

This trick is often used in Android.mk because NDK expects names of files in LOCAL_SRC_FILES to be *relative* to LOCAL_PATH.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the [Pattern Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) section of the `make` docs, the docs introduce you to the `%` character.  For example, here is a rule:

```
%.o : %.c
     recipe
```

That rule tells `make` how to create any `.o` file: make should look for a `.c` file and apply the recipe to it.  In the recipe, you can use `$<` for the full `.c` file name, and `$@` for the full `.o` file name.  For instance, here is a recipe:

```
gcc -c $< -o $@
```

`-c`  compile
`-o`  output file name

The docs present the `%` character again in the [Substitution References](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs) section of the `make` docs:

```
foo = a.o b.o c.o
bar := $(foo:%.o=%.c)
```

`:=`  expand into list of files right now

The first `%` in the pattern matches the file name without the extension, and the second `%` in the pattern inserts the previous match for %, so bar is assigned the list `a.c b.c c.c`.  This section also mentions:

> Another type of substitution reference lets you use the full power of
>   the patsubst function. It has the same form `$(var:a=b)`, except that now `a` must contain a single % character.

And in the [Functions for String Substitution and Analysis](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions) section of the `make` docs, it says:

> ```
> $(patsubst pattern,replacement,text)
> ```
>
> Finds whitespace-separated words in text that match pattern and replaces them with replacement.
>   Here pattern may contain a ‘%’ which acts as a wildcard, matching any
>   number of any characters within a word. If replacement also contains a
>   ‘%’, the ‘%’ is replaced by the text that matched the ‘%’ in pattern.
>
> ...   ...
>
> Substitution references (see Substitution References) are a simpler
>   way to get the effect of the patsubst function:
>
> ```
> $(var:pattern=replacement)
> ```

Your `substitution reference`:

```
$(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
```

uses the following values:

```
var         => FILE_LIST
pattern     => /Users/Jeff/dev/%   # $(LOCAL_PATH) is /Users/Jeff/dev/
replacement => %
```

If one of the file names in FILE_LIST looks like:

```
/Users/Jeff/dev/path/to/program.c
```

Then the pattern match lines up like this:

```
file name: /Users/Jeff/dev/path/to/program.c
  pattern: /Users/Jeff/dev/%
```

and `%` matches `path/to/program.c`.  And because the replacement is just `%`, the file name `/Users/Jeff/dev/path/to/program.c` is converted to `path/to/program.c`  As a result, all the files in FILE_LIST will have the prefix `/Users/Jeff/dev/` removed.